# Is there a Perl or Python library for ID3 metadata?

Tags: python, perl, id3

Basically, I've got a bunch of music files yoinked from my brother's iPod that retain their metadata but have those absolutely horrendous four character names the iPod seems to like storing them under. I figured I'd write a nice, quick script to just rename them as I wished, but I'm curious about any good libraries for reading ID3 metadata. I'd prefer either Perl or Python. I'm comfortable with Perl since I use it at work,  whereas Python I need more practice in and it'll make my Python evangelist friends happy.

Anyway, shortened version: Can you name a good library/module for either Python or Perl that will allow me to easily extract ID3 metadata from a pile of mp3s?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[MP3::Tag](http://search.cpan.org/~ilyaz/MP3-Tag-1.11/lib/MP3/Tag.pm) is a also great. Again, if you are looking for a Perl module, head over to search.cpan.org first.

```
 use MP3::Tag;

  $mp3 = MP3::Tag->new($filename);

  # get some information about the file in the easiest way
  ($title, $track, $artist, $album, $comment, $year, $genre) = $mp3->autoinfo();
  # Or:
  $comment = $mp3->comment();
  $dedicated_to
    = $mp3->select_id3v2_frame_by_descr('COMM(fre,fra,eng,#0)[dedicated to]');

  $mp3->title_set('New title');         # Edit in-memory copy
  $mp3->select_id3v2_frame_by_descr('TALB', 'New album name'); # Edit in memory
  $mp3->select_id3v2_frame_by_descr('RBUF', $n1, $n2, $n3);    # Edit in memory
  $mp3->update_tags(year => 1866);      # Edit in-memory, and commit to file
  $mp3->update_tags();                  # Commit to file
```

Comment: Well, http://metacpan.org has a nicer look and feel than search.cpan.org. But, yes, CPAN has all the answers :)

Answer (score 9):

[CPAN Search](http://www.metacpan.org/) turns up several Perl modules when you [search for ID3](http://search.cpan.org/search?query=ID3&mode=all). The answer to almost any Perl question  that starts with "Is there a library..." is to check CPAN.

I tend to like [MP3::Tag](http://www.metacpan.org/module/MP3::Tag/), but old people like me tend to find something suitable and ignore all advances in technology until we are forced to change.

Answer (score 5):

here are few python libs

http://id3-py.sourceforge.net/

http://nedbatchelder.com/code/modules/id3reader.html

http://code.google.com/p/mutagen/ [updated URL]

Comment: I have used mutagen before, it works very well.

Comment: ive used mutagen's `EasyID3` class a lot, and its great on the whole. it can't read tags that aren't at the beginning of a file, though, which is a downer.

Answer (score 4):

http://www.id3.org/Implementations

Comment: The link is rot now.

Answer (score 2):

I've had good luck with [MP3::Info](http://search.cpan.org/dist/MP3-Info).

Answer (score 1):

I think this snippet: [Rename MP3 files from ID3 tags](http://code.activestate.com/recipes/576811/) from python recipies might be helpful. It uses [id3reader](http://nedbatchelder.com/code/modules/id3reader.html) lib.

Answer (score 0):

The [Python Package Index](http://pypi.python.org/pypi) has a list of python packages matching a search for 'id3' [here](http://pypi.python.org/pypi?%3Aaction=search&term=id3&submit=search), the top several of which appear to be related to your needs. As with brian's answer above, the answer to any "is there a python module that..." probably starts with PyPI.