# Command line tool to edit mp3 ID3 tags

Tags: mp3, id3-tag

I want a simple command line tool running on Windows Xp(or even cross platform) similar in functionality to Mp3tag to edit mp3 ID3 tags. I mostly want to organize my music according to artist , genre etc so a lightweight tool which can ask the user which tag to edit and then change all the mp3 files' tags in a directory will be good. Can I use perl to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

yes indeed, you can use Perl to do it. (as well as other languages with such modules support). Search CPAN for [ID3 tag modules.](http://search.cpan.org/~ilyaz/MP3-Tag-0.92/Tag/ID3v2.pm)

Answer (score 4):

use http://eyed3.nicfit.net/ . it's in python. python works on windows.

Answer (score 2):

Sure you can; see [Is there a Perl or Python library for ID3 metadata?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1000132/is-there-a-perl-or-python-library-for-id3-metadata).

Answer (score 2):

I use mpgtx in my Debian, but I see they have a Windows version at http://mpgtx.sourceforge.net/#Download

The commands I use are as follows:

```
 # Read Tag information from mp3
 mpginfo 05\ Fatty\ Boom\ Boom.mp3

 # Writes album information in mp3
 tagmp3 set "%a:Tension" 05\ Fatty\ Boom\ Boom.mp3
```

Answer (score 1):

I just found the most powerful combination for doing this kind of work from a console: PowerShell and TagLib#.

Found it at http://huddledmasses.org/editing-media-tags-from-powershell/

It works like a charm!

Answer (score 1):

I use BulkID3 for this.  http://sourceforge.net/projects/bulkid3

I don't think it works on Windows, but it's open source.