# How can I remove the copyright tag from ID3 of mp3s in python or php?

Tags: php, python, id3

I have a bunch of mp3 files that are pretty old and don't have any copy rights. Yet, the place I got them from has filled the copy right tags with its own website url.

I was wondering if there's an easy way to remove these tags programmatically? There's a winamp add on that allows me to do this for each song, but that's not very feasible.

Edit: Is copyright part of the ID3 tags?

Thanks,
-Roozbeh

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1000132/is-there-a-perl-or-python-library-for-id3-metadata

Comment: Apart from the tecnichal side: your "mp3" files would need to be indeed pretty old in order to have no copyright - as copyright is for the music, not the file, and even then, it spams for 70 yearss after the authors's death. So - you'd be either dealing with pre 1920's music - or dealing with music which the authors explicitly put in the public domain, in order for them to have "no copyright".

Comment: They are pretty old and not even English...

Answer (score 8, accepted):

For Python, there's the [`mutagen`](https://github.com/quodlibet/mutagen) library and tool, which is very easy to use.

However if you're not looking to actually do this programmatically, on Windows there's the freeware app [MP3Tag](http://www.mp3tag.de/en/), which I can heartily recommend. It'll do batch transformations and lots more.

Comment: BTW, this works great on my MAC, but when I run my code on Windows, it removes all ID3 Tags, and won't allow me to modify the tags any more... not even manually... Is there a reason for this behavior in Windows?

Answer (score 3):

You can use [getID3](http://getid3.sourceforge.net/) library.

Here is the example:

```
<?php

$TaggingFormat = 'UTF-8';

require_once('../getid3/getid3.php');
// Initialize getID3 engine
$getID3 = new getID3;
$getID3->setOption(array('encoding'=>$TaggingFormat));

require_once('../getid3/write.php');
// Initialize getID3 tag-writing module
$tagwriter = new getid3_writetags;
//$tagwriter->filename = '/path/to/file.mp3';
$tagwriter->filename = 'd:/file.mp3';
                                                            $tagwriter->filename       = 'P:/webroot/_dev/getID3/testfiles/_writing/2011-02-02/test.mp3';
//$tagwriter->tagformats = array('id3v1', 'id3v2.3');
$tagwriter->tagformats = array('id3v2.3');

// set various options (optional)
$tagwriter->overwrite_tags = true;
                                                            $tagwriter->overwrite_tags = false;
$tagwriter->tag_encoding   = $TaggingFormat;
$tagwriter->remove_other_tags = true;

// populate data array
$TagData = array(
    'title'   => array('My Song'),
    'artist'  => array('The Artist'),
    'album'   => array('Greatest Hits'),
    'year'    => array('2004'),
    'genre'   => array('Rock'),
    'comment' => array('excellent!'),
    'track'   => array('04/16'),
);
$tagwriter->tag_data = $TagData;

// write tags
if ($tagwriter->WriteTags()) {
    echo 'Successfully wrote tags<br>';
    if (!empty($tagwriter->warnings)) {
        echo 'There were some warnings:<br>'.implode('<br><br>', $tagwriter->warnings);
    }
} else {
    echo 'Failed to write tags!<br>'.implode('<br><br>', $tagwriter->errors);
}

?>
```

Answer (score 2):

You can just use VLC player. Click on Tools->Media Information

Answer (score 1):

My solution, change path you want:

```
import os
import shutil
from mutagen.mp3 import MP3
for root, dirs, files in os.walk(path):
    for file in files:
        if file.endswith('.mp3'):
            f = os.path.join(root, file)
            try:
                mp3 = MP3(f)
                mp3.delete()
                mp3.save()
                print('ok')
            except:
                print('no ID3 tag')
print('Done')
```

Answer (score 0):

There are open source tools like Amarok which will let you make batch changes to ID3 tags.

Take a look at: http://amarok.kde.org/

Comment: Does it allow batch changes to the copy right tag specifically? I have tried a few programs like the auto tag add on on winamp which allows batch changes to some tags but not the copy right tag.

Comment: In fact, something like auto tag add on on winamp would be ideal if it would replace the made up copy right with the actual copy right.

Comment: I'm sorry, on further inspection, it seems Amarok doesn't cater for that tag. If you are familiar with PHP, take a look at http://php.net/manual/en/ref.id3.php . There is a very simple, programatic way to retrieve and remove id3 tags from mp3 files.

Answer (score 0):

Yes Yes This works!
Just download the latest version of VLC media player. Open the mp3 file in it. 
Right click on file > choose 'information' > edit publisher & copyright information there > click 'Save Metadata' below.
And u r done. :)

Answer (score -1):

No Need Of any PHP code
Just Reproduce the mp3 file i.e.either burn & rip or cut the size &time making a new file where you can specify your own multitudes of options

Comment: This is a lot of work for dropping the ID3 tags of just one track let alone many tracks as the OP mentioned. Not to mention the possibility of losing quality by reprocessing, etc.